# What does it mean when a KinematicBody2D is stored in a JSON file - Godot?

Tags: json, nodes, loading, godot, gdscript

After writing a few files for saving in my JSON file in Godot. I saved the information in a variable called `LData` and it is working. `LData` looks like this:

```
{
  "ingredients":[
    "[KinematicBody2D:1370]"
  ],
  "collected":[
    {
      "iname":"Pineapple",
      "collected":true
    },{
      "iname":"Banana",
      "collected":false
    }
  ]
}
```

What does it mean when the file says `KinematicBody2D:1370`? I understand that it is saving the node in the file - or is it just saving a string? Is it saving the node's properties as well?

When I  tried retrieving data  - a variable that is assigned to the saved `KinematicBody2D`.

Code:

```
for ingredient in LData.ingredients:
        print(ingredient.iname)
```

Error:

> Invalid get index name 'iname' (on base: 'String')

I am assuming that the data is stored as a String and I need to put some code to get the exact node it saved. Using `get_node` is also throwing an error.

Code:

```
for ingredient in LData.ingredients:
        print(get_node(ingredient).iname)
```

Error:

> Invalid get index 'iname' (on base: 'null instance')

**What information is it exactly storing when it says `[KinematicBody2D:1370]`? How do I access the variable `iname` and any other variables - variables that are assigned to the node when the game is loaded - and is not changed through the entire game?**

Comment: I've pretty print the JSON. Your code is accessing the wrong keys. Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi, sorry I rejected the edit by mistake. I will take a look at your suggestion and get back. Thanks.

Comment: Reedited ... you should use `LData.collected` to get to `iname`

Comment: Hi. I was trying to access a variable that is also called iname - inside the Kinematic body stored in the first array. I am not trying to access iname of collected data. How do I go about that?

Comment: `for ingredient in LData.ingredients:
        print(ingredient) # string` and `for ingredient in LData.ingredients:
        print(get_node(ingredient)` are ok ... for ingredient in `LData.collected:
        print(iname)` should get your the iname's

Comment: When I `print(get_node(ingredients))`,  it returns a null object. When I `print(ingredients)` it prints strings of the KinematicBody2D. I am not concerned about the `iname` in `LData.collected` as I know how to access it.

Answer (score 0):

`[KinematicBody2D:1370]` is just the string representation of a `Node`, which comes from [`Object.to_string`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_object.html#id5):

> Returns a String representing the object. If not overridden, defaults to "[ClassName:RID]".

If you truly want to serialize an entire Object, you could use [`Marshalls.variant_to_base64`](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/classes/class_marshalls.html#class-marshalls-method-variant-to-base64) and put that string in your json file. However, this will likely bloat your json file and contain much more information than you actually need to save a game. Do you really need to save an entire `KinematicBody`, or can you figure out the few properties that need to be saved (postion, type of object, ect.) and reconstruct the rest at runtime?

You can also save objects as `Resources`, which is more powerful and flexible than a JSON file, but tends to be better suited to game assets than save games. However, you could read the [Resource docs](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/latest/getting_started/step_by_step/resources.html#creating-your-own-resources) and see if saving `Resources` seems like a more appropriate solution to you.

Comment: 1) Is there a method to convert the String to Object? All I want is the code to just recognize the existing Kinematic Object and refer it. 2) Could you please share the syntax to use the Marshalls.variant_to_base64?  3) I don't need to save the entire KinematicBody. I have tired the Resources method previously but I didn't really understand how to make it work using the documentation. Which method do you suggest to use to save data for a 2D Pixel RPG? I am currently using the JSON method you suggested in my previous question.